# Strange background color on external drive folder names

Tags: macos, external-disk, folders

I had folder on local Mac drive. And when I `ls` on terminal I see this:

[image]

But when I copied on external HDD (FAT filesystem) I see this when I call the same `ls` command in the same directory:

[image]

What does the background color mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means that you and every body have permissions to write over directories. On your mac drive only you have perms to write inside.

Note that you folder on mac drive have perms `drwxr-xr-x`, and your external hd have `drwxrwxrwx`.

[How to Set File Permissions in Mac OS X](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415)

Comment: You are completely right, but I cannot remove write permission on "other". When  I write `chmod w-o FolderName` it does not take effect on external drive.

Comment: This is because FAT filesystem does not support permissions. By default, all file have all perms. [http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Comparing-NTFS-and-FAT-file-systems](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Comparing-NTFS-and-FAT-file-systems)

Comment: What about ExFAT? I know this works on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: ExFAT support permissions. [Check this comparative table](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm).